# Using .htaccess to get content from directory for sub-domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, url-rewriting

I've read a tonne of questions on this and tried a few solutions, but I'm just not getting the results I want.

I'm currently using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cp\.example\.net
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.net/gamepanel/public/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Which doesn't quite work as intended. When I navigate to `cp.example.net` I am redirected to `http://example.net/gamepanel/public/`

What I want to have happen is for `cp.example.net` to show the content at `http://example.net/gamepanel/public`, whilst showing the subdomain in the URL.

Also `cp.example.net/user` should show content from `example.net/gamepanel/public/user`

Some help on achieving this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was a little off the mark on what I needed to do and that .htaccess wasn't the best way to do this.

Adding this in my apache files solved it

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName cp.example.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/gamepanel/public
        <Directory /var/www/gamepanel/public>
            Options -Indexes
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```